# How to control submitting form if fileupload contains no file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, button, file-upload

Good day everyone, I would like to ask you on how to control submitting form if there is no file in fileupload. My code for uploading file is this.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

string name = fi.Name;
string extn = fi.Extension;

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;

cs.Open();
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
cs.Close();
```

If there is no file selected and the submit button is clicked, I want something that will restrict this to be stored on the database. I don't know what to put in the if-else statement. Please help me.

Comment: Also consider one aspect: may be somebody fill select file, but file is empty. So check also for File length. FileUpload1.Content.Length > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your Filename directly whether it contains any data or not.

Like :

```
 if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
 {
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

string name = fi.Name;
string extn = fi.Extension;

// Add Connection string here //

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;

cs.Open();
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
cs.Close();
}
else
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('No Files Uploaded');", true);
}
```

**Update** : I think there is a problem in ur code. U have used

```
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;
```

to insert data . So try below method to insert data

```
if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
 {
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
 byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

 string name = fi.Name;
 string extn = fi.Extension;

 SqlConnection connections = new SqlConnection(strConn);
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename(DocumentName, DocumentContent, DocumentExt) VALUES (@DocumentName, @DocumentContent, @DocumentExt)", connections);

 SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
              param0.Value = name;
              command.Parameters.Add(param0);

 SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
              param1.Value = documentContent;
              command.Parameters.Add(param1);

 SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
              param2.Value = extn;
              command.Parameters.Add(param2);
connections.Open();
int numRowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connections.Close();

   if (numRowsAffected != 0)
     {
     Response.Write("<BR>Rows Inserted successfully");
     }
   else
     {
    Response.Write("<BR>An error occurred uploading the image");
     }
  }
else
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('No Files Uploaded');", true);
}
```

Comment: Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@DocumentName". On da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: i think you are calling connection string above if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
 { }

Comment: That error is because , your sql command insert query is outside the { }. So,You have to call all your connection and command string inside the { }.  Its Something like, if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
 { //all ur code including connection string , sql command and da declaration }

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick for you

```
string name = fi.Name;
string extn = fi.Extension;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;

    cs.Open();
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cs.Close();
}
```

So when we check the `String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)` method. It checks for file name to be blank or not. If there is no file selected and the value is none than it would not go to call the SQL things.

Comment: Error: The path is not of a legal form. Shows up at FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Required] tag over the property in your model. You can add responses and other stuff using validation.

Comment: Your tip only for project on MVC framework. For a web-forms it will differ. Next time consider this aspect also please

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which one you need: 
1. restrict from submit(postback), Add in RequiredFieldValidator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Validation1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage="An image file is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

2. Do not save only the image:

```
`if(FileUpload1 != null && FileUpload1.FileName!= "")`
```

Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

Use following scenario:

```
  ListBox lbAttachments = (ListBox)FileUpload1;
  if(lbAttachments.Items.Count > 0)
  {
         for(int i = 0; i < lstAttachments.Items.Count; i++)
         {
               FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(lbAttachments.Items[i].Text);
               byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

               string name = fi.Name;
               string extn = fi.Extension;
               SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("Insert into tableName(DocumentName,DocumentContent, DocumentExt) Values(@DocumentName,@DocumentContent,@DocumentExt)", con);
               SqlParameter Name = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
               SqlParameter DocumentContent = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.Int);
               SqlParameter DocumentExt= cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
               da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
               da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
               da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;

               cs.Open();
               da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
               cs.Close();
         } 
   }
```

//Another Way is

```
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)//To check file os present
{
    if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    byte[] documentContent = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

                    string name = fi.Name;
                    string extn = fi.Extension;
                    SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("Insert into tableName(DocumentName,DocumentContent, DocumentExt) Values(@DocumentName,@DocumentContent,@DocumentExt)", con);
                    SqlParameter Name = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                    SqlParameter DocumentContent = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter DocumentExt= cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocumentExt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;

                    cs.Open();
                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cs.Close(); 
               }
         }
```

Comment: There is an error in (ListBox)FileUpload1; cannot convert type fileupload to listbox

Comment: You can also use following properties to check file is present or not:                                                                                                                           if(FileUpload1.HasFile)//To check file os present
                {
               if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                      {
       //Your Code.
        }
                }

Comment: I already tried it. Then the error is. Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@DocumentName". On da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You can try above methods.

Comment: For ListBox functionality you must add Listbox cotrol along with buttons and FileUpload control. On clicking Add button must add Fileupload content to Listbox. Using this functionality you can upload multiple files at a time.

Comment: Is this problem still exists?

Comment: Yes, do you have another suggestion?